# how monitor whether filebeat is receiving log from specified path?

Tags: logstash, filebeat, statsd

I have installed logstash on a server for gathering logs from a number of client servers by installing filebeat on all of client servers and every thing works well. 
now I need to receive alarm if each of client servers do not send any logs to filebeat ( In other words, I want to receive alarm through email when no log is produced because for example my code is down). is possible to do that with statsd plugin and if so, how can I do that?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've used two techniques for this:

1. setup a check in your monitoring system of choice (e.g. sensu) that compared the entries in filebeat's registry file with the actual sizes of the files being sent.  If the % gets too low, send an alert.
2. watch for logs coming into your ES server.  Depending on your specific needs, you can query to see if any logs have been received in X minutes, or if X machines have reported log files in Y minutes, or...  Elastic's `watcher` is pretty good at this, but it's also easy to write yourself.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. but I am completely new in logstash could you please explain more how can I use Elastic's watcher for these  purpose. and as I have several client it is important for me to know which machine has not sent any logs for for example 1 hour? I have installed x-pack but I don't know how can I write a watcher for this purpose, assume I have the IP of each client server and my log indices by date for example logstash-2017.10.07. thank you

Comment: Imagine a query that counted the unique hosts that sent in logs in the last 5 minutes.  If you have 72 machines, you would expect that number to always be 72.  I believe that watcher can run the query, compare the result to 72, and alert you.  There are other ways that would give you more flexibility, too.